# Confusing paragraph about Bayesian priors and marginal likelihood

Tags: conditional-probability, bayesian

I'm somewhat confused by the following paragraph, taken from [Koller's book](http://pgm.stanford.edu) ,  on how $P(D)$ is the "probability of seeing this particular data set **given** our prior beliefs".  I would have thought that was the definition of $P(D|\theta)$, not $P(D)$. Furthermore, if we integrate over all $\theta$, then how would it matter what prior beliefs we have for $\theta$? That is, how would $P(D)$ change if we change beliefs about $\theta$?

[image: a priori]

Comment: Can you give the page number for this?

Comment: @Bitwise pg. 738

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following rather curious question:

> Suppose that you witness a series of ten coin tosses.  All of the
>   tosses come up heads.  What is the probability that this is a
>   two-headed coin?

Your data $\mathcal D$ is "the coin came up heads ten times in a row". The parameter $\theta$ is either "the coin is fair" or "the coin has two heads".

We're dealing with discrete rather than continuous probability here, so we'll replace the integral sign with a summation sign and the equation from the text becomes,

$$P(\mathcal D) = \sum_\theta P(\mathcal D | \theta) P(\theta)$$

which in this case expands to

$$
\begin{align}
P(\mathcal D) = & P(\mathcal D \mid \textrm{"coin is fair"}) \cdot P(\textrm{"coin is fair"})\\ + & P(\mathcal D \mid \textrm{"coin has two heads"}) \cdot P(\textrm{"coin has two heads"})
\end{align}
$$

It's obvious that

$$P(\mathcal D \mid \textrm{"coin is fair"}) = \frac{1}{2^{10}}$$

and

$$P(\mathcal D \mid \textrm{"coin has two heads"}) = 1$$

But how on Earth are you supposed to evaluate $P(\textrm{"coin is fair"})$ or $P(\textrm{"coin has two heads"})$?  Mathematics alone doesn't have an answer to that question. You need to supply one based on common sense.  The answer you choose to supply is called your *Bayesian prior*.

If you believe, for example, that you have a one in five hundred chance of encountering a two-headed coin given whatever particular set of circumstances you find yourself in, then the calculation becomes:

$$P(\mathcal D) = \frac{1}{2^{10}} \cdot \frac{499}{500} + 1 \cdot \frac{1}{500}   \approx 2.975 \cdot 10^{-3}$$

In other words, seeing the ten heads in a row is a pretty surprising result.

However, given this result, we can now use Bayes' law to calculate $P(\textrm{"coin has two heads"} \mid \mathcal D)$, which is your *posterior* belief in the likelihood of this being a two-headed coin.

$$
\begin{align}
P(\textrm{"coin has two heads"} \mid \mathcal D)  = & \frac{P(\mathcal D \mid \textrm{"coin has two heads"}) \cdot P(\textrm{"coin has two heads"})}{P(\mathcal D)} \\ \approx & \frac{1 \cdot \frac{1}{500}}{2.975 \cdot 10^{-3}} \\
\approx & \mathbf{0.6723}
\end{align}
$$

Which is the answer to the question I posed to you.

You asked, "how would $P(\mathcal D)$ change if we change beliefs about $\theta$?".

Well, let's say that instead of this experiment taking place at a reputable casino in Vegas, it took place at a seedy carnival booth.  Your prior estimation of the likelihood of seeing a two-headed coin would then be considerably higher: let's say one in ten.  Now you calcuate,

$$P(\mathcal D) = \frac{1}{2^{10}} \cdot \frac{9}{10} + 1 \cdot \frac{1}{10} \approx 0.10088$$

meaning you're a lot less suprised than before at seeing the ten heads in a row.  This is why $P(\mathcal D)$ depends on your beliefs about $P(\theta)$.